# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePassword does not exist

Tags: laravel-livewire

How do I perform this validation in Livewire?

It works in Laravel but not in Livewire. I get the error:

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePassword does not exist

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|Password::min(8)
            
            ->mixedCase()
            ->letters()
            ->numbers()
            ->symbols()
            ->uncompromised()
            ',
```

When I have this:

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8
                
                ->mixedCase()
                ->letters()
                ->numbers()
                ->symbols()
                ->uncompromised()
```

I get error for mixedCase, letters, etc.

Comment: @Kirk, thanks for your answer but that doesnt work in livewire. When do the array method of giving rules in livewire, I get this error "Constant expression contains invalid operations". Livewire requires | for real time validation